# Vivado can't recognize the double-port RAM while using SyncReadMem

Tags: chisel

I want to create a true double-port RAM in Chisel and synthesize the Verilog code in Vivado 2018.3. Here is my Chisel code:

```scala
class DoublePortsRAM extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle { 
    val addr1 = Input(UInt(10.W))
    val dataIn1 = Input(UInt(32.W))
    val en1 = Input(Bool())
    val we1 = Input(Bool())
    val dataOut1 = Output(UInt(32.W))
    val clk2 = Input(Clock())
    val reset2 = Input(Bool())
    val addr2 = Input(UInt(10.W))
    val dataIn2 = Input(UInt(32.W))
    val en2 = Input(Bool())
    val we2 = Input(Bool())
    val dataOut2 = Output(UInt(32.W))  
  })

  val syncRAM = SyncReadMem(1024, UInt(32.W))

  when(io.en1) {
    when(io.we1) {
      syncRAM.write(io.addr1, io.dataIn1)
      io.dataOut1 := DontCare
    } .otherwise {
      io.dataOut1 := syncRAM.read(io.addr1)
    }
  } .otherwise {
    io.dataOut1 := DontCare
  }

  withClockAndReset(io.clk2, io.reset2) {
    when(io.en2) {
      when(io.we2) {
        syncRAM.write(io.addr2, io.dataIn2)
        io.dataOut2 := DontCare
      } .otherwise {
        io.dataOut2 := syncRAM.read(io.addr2)
      }
    } .otherwise {
      io.dataOut2 := DontCare
    }
  }
}
```

After compiling it, some Verilog codes like these:

```verilog
  always @(posedge clock) begin
    ...
    if (_GEN_36) begin
      syncRAM__T_1_addr_pipe_0 <= io_addr1;
    end
  end
...
  assign syncRAM__T_1_addr = syncRAM__T_1_addr_pipe_0;
  assign syncRAM__T_1_data = syncRAM[syncRAM__T_1_addr]; 
  assign io_dataOut1 = syncRAM__T_1_data;
...
```

However, Vivado reports that it can't infer the pattern of the RAM. I must modify the Verilog code manually to these:

```verilog
  always @(posedge clock) begin
    ...
    if (_GEN_36) begin
      syncRAM__T_1_addr_pipe_0 <= syncRAM[io_addr1];
    end
  end
... 
  assign io_dataOut1 = syncRAM__T_1_addr_pipe_0;
...
```

In other words, the Synchronous Read RAM shouldn't use a register to store the reading address. On the contrary, it is OK to store the reading data. In addition, Vivado can synthesize the single-port RAM without modifying the Verilog. What's wrong with it?

Comment: It is strange to me that it works fine for a single-port RAM but not for a dual-port RAM. In any case, this should be fixed, could you file an issue on FIRRTL? https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl/issues

Comment: Yes. I think so, too.